# searching for repeated properties in objects in an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find out if one user appears more than once in the associative array (and then sum the value of the same tasks). How do I do that in javaScript?

```
    {
  "Items": [
    {
      "Date": {
        "N": "1439883817221"
      },
      "UserName": {
        "S": "user1"
      },
      "task1": {
        "N": "9"
      }
    },
    {
      "Date": {
        "N": "1439892361108"
      },
      "task2": {
        "N": "3"
      },
      "UserName": {
        "S": "user2"
      }
    },
    {
      "Date": {
        "N": "1439904242126"
      },
      "UserName": {
        "S": "user1"
      },
      "task2": {
        "N": "2"
      }
    }
}}
```

Comment: You need to show the code you've worked on so far (add it to the question). SO doesn't do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var uniqueNames = [];
var nonUniqueNames = [];
$.each( list.Items, function(i, item ) {

    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(item.UserName.S) != -1 ){
        nonUniqueNames.push(item.UserName.S);   
    } else { 
        uniqueNames.push(item.UserName.S);  
    }

});

      alert(nonUniqueNames);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c2co1hck/

As for the same tasks you can figure out the same way to do it. 
Please define the same tasks anyway as you have different names and values for it.

Posting some of your code would also be appreciated.

By the way you have an error in your JSON, it should end with 
]} not with }}